# How do I convert DateTime to String while using IQueryable and Project().To<>()

Tags: c#, linq, automapper, projection, iqueryable

I've tried a variety of things I've read but nothing seems to work as expected.

Some back story, I'm creating OData [Queryable] endpoints with WebApi. I have DateTime fields in my Entities, but I need them to be strings, or DateTimeOffsets in my APIModel since WebAPI currently forbids DateTimes.

```
//Repository call (returns IQueryable<Schedule>):
_ECFRepository.GetScheduleByDateRange(start_date, end_date).Project().To<ScheduleAPIModel>();
```

Setting up ProjectUsing causes all my data to come back unitialized:

```
 //Even if set ScheduleAPIModels to a constant value they show up as null
 Mapper.CreateMap<Schedule, ScheduleAPIModel>()
    .ProjectUsing(p =>
        new ScheduleAPIModel()
        {
            sd_dtset = p.sd_dtset == null ? "" : ((DateTime)p.sd_dtset).ToShortDateString(),
            sd_dtsatis = p.sd_dtsatis == null ? "" : ((DateTime)p.sd_dtsatis).ToShortDateString(),
        });
```

[Custom type converter](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) doesn't seem to work either, I end up with this error:

```
Type 'System.String' does not have a default constructor
```

I also tried using a MapFrom, but Linq doesn't like ToString() operations inline so something like this won't work either:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Schedule, ScheduleAPIModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.sd_dtset, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => ((DateTime)src.sd_dtsatis).ToShortDateString()))

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I'm trying to keep this as IQueryable because OData's querys are applied at runtime, and using ODataQueryOptions would require me to expose my Entities.

Hopefully I'm just making some kind of simple mistake with Project/ProjectUsing.

Edit: I am able to get around this problem by mapping the DateTime field to a DateTime field in my DTO that I set to Ignore in the EntitySet and exposing an Entity member that does the string conversion in it's getter. But I wish there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: AutoMapper is apparently not able to convert `ToShortDateString()` to an actual SQL query. I think you will have to materialize the query results before the projection or simplify the projection so that it can be translated to SQL.

Comment: This is not AutoMapper but the underlying LINQ provider.

Comment: Yeah, it's rough especially since I don't want to lose the IQueryable performance.

Comment: Are you using JSON as your on-the-wire format?